# Update value - plus and minus

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'd like to create a simple rater with php/ajax, which:

1) after clicking on plus refreshes the number of "thumbs up" +1
2) after clicking on minus refreshes the number of "thumbs down" -1
3) in both cases sends a mysql query to update the table - and it all should be without refreshing a page.

As I'm not really good at ajax stuff, I ask you for help. How to do that? I thought about load() function, but there would be loads of comments to rate, so writing each of them load() function will be really uncool. Please, provide me with some ideas, if possible with the examples. I count on you!

Paweł

PS This might be done with jquery, I dont mind.

As for now, I've tried to make adding numbers itself possible. But it is not working. Here is my html:

```
<a rel='tooltip' href='#ocentemat' title='Zgadzam się!' class='addplus'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i></a> <span class='plusy'>1</span>
```

and my scripting:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(\".addplus\").click(function() {
     var currentValue = parseInt($(\"span.plusy\").text(),1);
 $('span.plusy').text(currentValue);
    });
});
```

Comment: "I count on you!"..... now that's just classic! - Show us what you've accomplished thus far in achieving your goal

Comment: Dear cube, thanks for a fast reply. I've updated my first post - hope we can come up with adding number idea together and then proceed to sending data to mysql :)

Comment: @Pawel you can use this script for start http://jsfiddle.net/xQRbd/

Comment: Thank you, @Manish. I have one more question for now: is there any possibility to attach few classes to one jqery script, i mean something like in preg_* function, to make the function work for .addplus, .addplus1, .addplus2 seperately? Thanks for help.

Comment: don't make multiple classes. same class can be used for all. eg http://jsfiddle.net/code_snips/VuKwt/

Comment: After hours spent on figuring out how to do that, i've decided to use php method with a refresh of page. Using ajax exceeded my knowledge. Thanks for your help though :)